# how to generate a new array in perl each time a loop runs

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I am running a loop and each time i need to store some information in a new array. How to generate a new array each time the loop runs like @array1, @array2 , @array3 and so on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review [help] about how to ask questions here.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is an array of arrays, i.e. a multi-dimensional array.

```
my @arrays;
for my $i(0..10)
{
    $arrays[$i] = ['data1', 'data2'];
}

print $arrays[0][0];
print $arrays[0][1];
```

Comment: The question is completely unclear, and should not be answered in its current state. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Eh, no, it's pretty clear. Not the best writing, but still easy to understand.